# Shoot raycast on reflect direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm creating a pool game. And I want to shoot `Raycast` on the reflect direction so I can draw `LineRenderer` on it.

[image]

**Main Cue Ball Script:**

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class DrawCueBallTrajectory : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private RaycastHit hit;
    
        private LineRenderer lineRender;
    
        private float cueBallRadius;
         
        private void Awake()
        {
            lineRender = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    
            cueBallRadius = GetComponent<SphereCollider>().radius;
        }
    
        void Update()
        {
            Vector3 reduceTransPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 2f, transform.position.z);
    
            Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, -transform.forward);
    
            if (Physics.SphereCast(ray, cueBallRadius, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.collider != null)
                {
                    lineRender.enabled = true;
    
                    lineRender.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
                    lineRender.SetPosition(1, -transform.forward + new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y + 1f, hit.point.z));
    
                    if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("OtherCueBall"))
                    {
    
                        Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.Reflect(hit.transform.position, hit.normal);
    
                        hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<OtherCueBallTrajectory>().DrawPredictionLine(newDirection);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
    }
```

**Other Ball Script**

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class OtherCueBallTrajectory : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private RaycastHit hit;
    
        private LineRenderer lineRender;
    
        private float cueBallRadius;
    
        private void Awake()
        {
            lineRender = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    
            cueBallRadius = GetComponent<SphereCollider>().radius;
        }
    
        public void DrawPredictionLine(Vector3 targetDestination)
        {
    
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position); // what to put here

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must emit another sphere cast along the point of impact. Also adjust the `lineRender` points count according to the number of fractures. I made these changes to the script `main cue ball` and do not see the need to refer the second sphere cast to the `other ball`.

```cs
    if (Physics.SphereCast(ray, cueBallRadius, out hit))
    {
        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            lineRender.enabled = true;
    
            lineRender.positionCount = 2; // here I set lineRender position count

            lineRender.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
            lineRender.SetPosition(1, -transform.forward + new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y + 1f, hit.point.z));
    
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("OtherCueBall"))
            {
                Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.Reflect(hit.transform.position, hit.normal);
    
                lineRender.positionCount = 3; // we need 1 more break point
                
                // second sphere cast begin from hit.point along reflectDirection
                if (Physics.SphereCast(hit.point, cueBallRadius, newDirection, out var secondHit))
                {
                    lineRender.SetPosition(2, secondHit.point); // stop when hit wall or anything
                }
                else
                {
                    lineRender.SetPosition(2, hit.point + newDirection * 10f); // point along direction for maximum of 10f length for e.g..
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on this part 
 if (Physics.SphereCast(hit.point, newDirection, out var secondHit))

Comment: add radius to parameters, sorry I forgot: Physics.SphereCast(hit.point, cueBallRadius, newDirection, out var secondHit))

Comment: sorry but its giving me the wrong trajectory

Comment: The tragectory path is taken from Vector3.Reflect (hit.transform.position, hit.normal) which is based on the angle of refraction on the normal vector. Consider the initial hit point is taken from the sphere cast, it may be confused in detecting the direction on sphere shape objects. Since your question is broad, only generalities can be targeted and details should be raised in other questions.